# Sharing reels from custom app works but instagram fails to finish uploading them

Tags: ios, swift

I used https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2023/10/12/sharing-to-reels-instagram-available-to-developers/?content_id=RPqmZdVrnkeJq63 their code to implement to my app. I am able to load the reel into the instagram reel view and edit it and add title and hashtags. But when I tap post, it starts to upload and then fails publishing it saying it was saved to drafts. But then I can post it from drafts or manually from my photos. Any ideas why is this happening? I feel like the pasteboard is not sending some data to instagram or what.

```
func shareToInstagram(videoURL: URL) {
        let appIDString = "883xxxxx"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: videoURL) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading video data: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let backgroundVideoData = data else {
                print("Did not receive any data")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.backgroundVideo(backgroundVideoData: backgroundVideoData, appID: appIDString)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func backgroundVideo(backgroundVideoData: Data, appID: String) {
        if let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-reels://share"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) {
            let pasteboardItems: [[String: Any]] = [
                ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundVideo": backgroundVideoData],
                ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.appID": appID]
            ]
            let pasteboardOptions = [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
            UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)
            UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
        } else {
            print("Instagram app is not installed or the URL scheme is not supported")
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of what could cause this is to do something with creating the app in meta developer portal to obtain the ID. But that's just my guess which could be wrong.

I tired different URL schemas etc but didn't have a success even preloading the video.